Error fetching a paginated list of users; what could be wrong?
I'm having a bit of trouble getting certain results as intended, using FastApi, Sqlalchemy, and Pydantic (v2) schemas.
Here's code I have running, abstracted for the purpose of this question:
database.py
class Base(DeclarativeBase, MappedAsDataclass):
    pass

model.py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[uuid_pkg.UUID] = mapped_column(default_factory=uuid_pkg.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)
    ....
    bank: Mapped["Bank"] = relationship("Bank", uselist=False, back_populates="user", default=None, lazy='selectin')




class Bank(Base):
    __tablename__ = "bank"

    id: Mapped[uuid_pkg.UUID] = mapped_column(default_factory=uuid_pkg.uuid4, primary_key=True, unique=True, index=True)

    account_number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), nullable=False, default=None)
    ...
    user_id: Mapped[uuid_pkg.UUID] = mapped_column(types.Uuid, ForeignKey("users.id"), default=None)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="bank")

Schema.py
class UserRead(BaseModel):
    id: uuid_pkg.UUID

    bank: Optional[BankBase]

    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)


class BankBase(BaseModel):
    name: Annotated[str, Field(min_length=2, examples=["bank name"])]
    account_number: Annotated[str, Field(min_length=2, max_length=10, examples=["account number"])]
    account_name: Annotated[str, Field(min_length=2, max_length=50, examples=["account name"])]

    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

Expected Result, even as indicated as the appropriate response under Responses for 200 status code:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-xxxxxx",
      "username": "gojos",
      "email": "gojosatoru@jjk.com",
      ....
      "created_at": "2024-05-17T00:59:58.682Z",
      "updated_at": "2024-05-17T00:59:58.682Z",
      "bank": {
        "name": "bank name",
        "account_number": "account number",
        "account_name": "account name"
      }
    }
  ],
  "total_count": 0,
  "has_more": true,
  "page": 0,
  "items_per_page": 0
}


The paginated data is coming through Fastcrud.
NOTE: When I run the /user/me endpoint, that only returns one schema, and not a list: everything works as intended:
{
  "id": "25f1a7e3-a47e-4493-84f2-xxxxx",
  "username": "gojos",
  "email": "gojosaturo@jjk.com",
  ....
  "created_at": "2024-05-16T22:06:17.617345Z",
  "updated_at": "2024-05-17T00:19:26.472494Z",
  "tier_id": null,
  "bank": {
    "name": "JJK Bank",
    "account_number": "0102939929",
    "account_name": "Gojo Satoru",
  },
}

Actual Result (ERROR: Internal Server Error):
    raise ResponseValidationError(
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 2 validation errors (2 because I have two users in DB):
  {'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response', 'data', 0, 'bank'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': False}      

  {'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response', 'data', 1, 'bank'), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': True}       


If I adapt the UserRead  Bank to be bool such as below, it works by returning true for the user with bank details (created through a ForeignKey) otherwise false:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-xxxxxx",
      "username": "gojos",
      "email": "gojosatoru@jjk.com",
      ....
      "created_at": "2024-05-17T00:59:58.682Z",
      "updated_at": "2024-05-17T00:59:58.682Z",
      "bank": true
    },
    {
      "id": "3fa85f64-xxxx-4562-xxxxx-xxxxxx",
      "username": "gojosx",
      "email": "gojosatorux@jjkx.com",
      ....
      "created_at": "2024-05-17T00:59:58.682Z",
      "updated_at": "2024-05-17T00:59:58.682Z",
      "bank": false
    },
  ],
  "total_count": 2,
  "has_more": false,
  "page": 0,
  "items_per_page": 0
}

The users/all endpoint uses:
    users_data = await crud_users.get_multi(
        db=db,
        offset=compute_offset(page, items_per_page),
        limit=items_per_page,
        schema_to_select=UserRead,
        is_deleted=False,
    )


    #the below is not working as well
    # users_data = await crud_users.get_multi_joined(
    # db=db,
    # joins_config=[JoinConfig(
    #     model= Bank,
    #     join_on= User.id == Bank.user_id,
    #     schema_to_select= UserRead,
    #     # join_prefix= 'ba_',
    #     join_type= 'left',
    # )],

    # nest_joins=True,
    # return_as_model=True,
    # schema_to_select=UserRead,
    # # join_schema_to_select=BankBase,
    # )

    response  = paginated_response(crud_data=users_data, page=page, items_per_page=items_per_page)

    return response

What can I do to get the full bank details instead of a boolean when using the users/all endpoint that returns a list of users in the DB?

  users_data = await crud_users.get_multi_joined(
       db=db,
       joins_config=[JoinConfig(
           model=Bank,
           join_on=User.id == Bank.user_id,
           join_prefix='bank_',
           join_type='left',
       )],
       nest_joins=True,
       schema_to_select=UserRead,
       offset=compute_offset(page, items_per_page),
       limit=items_per_page
       )

   response:  dict[str, Any] = paginated_response(crud_data=users_data, page=page, items_per_page=items_per_page)



A proper joining method resulted to the intended result. I had to go back to the FastCrud documentation (https://igorbenav.github.io/fastcrud/usage/crud/#2-get-joined) and read thoroughly. Surprisingly easy. And before that I had abandoned it to use sql join query. All good now.
